# calculate mean of each column, R

Tags: r, class, mean

I import a data.frame named "dataset1", and it has a column "O3". I want to calculate the mean for O3.

```
mean(dataset1$O3)
```

I have tried several other syntax versions, but it still gives the following error:

> Warning message: In mean.default(O3) : argument is not numeric or
>   logical: returning NA

I know it is a type problem, but I could not figure out. What should I do?

Comment: Please check the `str(dataset)`  It would be non-numeric.  If it is `factor` class, then do `mean(as.numeric(as.character(dataset1$O3)))`

Comment: @akrun thank you. now, it says "NA Warning message:
In mean(as.numeric(as.character(dataset1$O3))) : NAs introduced by coercion " I think I need to take care of missing values first.

Comment: nil, `mean` has `na.rm=TRUE` as well, but other than the warning is a friendly message, in case you have some character value, it gets automatically convert to NA `mean(as.numeric(as.character(dataset1$O3)), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: BTW: If you want to calculate the mean of **all** columns as indicated by your question head line (not only one as you are asking for in the details) you could use something like `colMeans(mtcars)` which works of course only if all the columns are numeric (so extract the numeric column beforehand).

Comment: Note that ``read.table``, ``read.csv`` and others may by default convert some columns (with characters) to ``factor``. You can prevent that behaviour in these functions with the parameter ``stringsAsFactors=F`` when reading the dataset from files.

Comment: @RYoda thank you, yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Phann thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @nil Please do never forget to add some test data to your question to give a reproducible example for answers. This may be the reason for down votes of your question (not me) - I am unhappy with down votes of new users without dropping a comment for the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can see [R's documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mean.html) and see that you could remove this warning adding `na.rm=T` as parameter in `mean`.

> na.rm
>   a logical value indicating whether NA values should be stripped before the computation proceeds.

The resulting code is:

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(dataset1$O3)), na.rm = T)
```